# why remesh grid not showing in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

Trying to re-mesh the object in 3.5 version, when i click shift+R it take me to object mode, When i press ctrl+R some geometry added but why the grid not visible, to increase the verts count or to make the mesh dense geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 3.5 it looks like the key is now simply <kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to apply)

[image]

Comment: Thanks as always